# Meaning of the word "any" in "ineligible for any exemption"

Tags: meaning-in-context, determiners

An important legal result hinges on the meaning of the word "any" in this sentence:

> "If the effect of the domiciliary requirement under subparagraph (A) is to render the debtor **ineligible for any exemption**, the debtor may elect to exempt property that is specified under subsection (d)."

My opposition argues that because the debtor is still eligible for some exemptions, he cannot elect to exempt property that is specified under subsection (d). I argue that the effect of the domiciliary requirement rendered my client ineligible for some exemptions, therefore I can elect to exempt property that is specified under subsection (d). It seems like it should be a simple issue, but it has now confused judges all the way up to the 9th Circuit Court of Appeals

In other words, one party argues that this sentence means: As long as the debtor is eligible for at least one exemption, the [result occurs].

The other party argues that this sentence means: If the debtor is ineligible for at least one exemption, the [result occurs].

Which is correct, and why?

Comment: I'm not a linguist, nor am I even a native English speaker, but I'm having a hard time seeing how the first interpretation is even possible. If the first one were true, I'm almost certain that (barring any other changes), the word would have to be *eligible*, and not *ineligible*, as it says now. I don't quite see how the sentence is ambiguous in the first place, could you include an explanation behind why there is an confusion? Doing so will probably help people in answering your question.

Comment: You got two creative messed-up distortions there. In #1, the [result **does not** occur]. In #2, there is a complete distortion of the plain reading of the clause. If the debtor is eligible for at least one exemption, the [result **does not** occur].

Comment: You could also get the first meaning if it began with "unless".

Comment: In my case, the debtor is eligible for a few exemptions. The debtor is also ineligible for a few exemptions. So, does the result occur or not?

Comment: The question is not sufficiently specified to make sense.  Could you please give the background context?  Are we talking about?  We seem to be dealing with a contract for a loan.  But there seems to be a condition related to non-payment.  So my guess is that the defendant has not paid the debt (or has fallen into arrears).  The lender is entitled to compensation unless some particular circumstance provided for in the contract applies.  The 'result' in that case would be some form of compensation to the lender (seizure of goods to the value of the amount owing, or whatever.  What's it about?

Comment: Tuffy, it's a statute. The full statute is: "If the effect of the domiciliary requirement under subparagraph (A) is to render the debtor ineligible for any exemption, the debtor may elect to exempt property that is specified under subsection (d)."

Comment: My opposition argues that because the debtor is still eligible for some exemptions, he cannot elect to exempt property that is specified under subsection (d). I argue that the effect of the domiciliary requirement rendered my client ineligible for some exemptions, therefore I can elect to exempt property that is specified under subsection (d). It seems like it should be a simple issue, but it has now confused judges all the way up to the 9th Circuit Court of Appeals.

Comment: Xanne, I disagree. It's not a legal question, it's a language question that comes from a statute. I *think* it comes down to this: Does "ineligible for any exemption" mean not eligible for a single exemption at all, or does "ineligible for any exemption" mean not eligible for some of the exemptions.

Comment: Edwin, very helpful link, thanks.

Comment: Essentially, the parties should agree that the statement is ambiguous and needs clarifying.

Comment: It's US Code. It *might* get another look by Congress in 10 or 20 years. So, I need to convince the 9th Circuit which reading is more logical. Of course, there are legal arguments I will make. But, I am in this forum to see if there are grammatical arguments.

Comment: As your question has been closed I couldn't post an additional answer, but I did post it on the page of the question to which your question has been referred for solutions (https://english.stackexchange.com/q/312724/349876).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: this answer deals only with the English language aspects on an amateur basis, not with legal aspects, and not on a professional basis.*

*Any* can be used in several ways, two of which are defined in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/any) as:

> **any** *determiner*
> 2 Used to express a lack of restriction in selecting one of a specified class.
> ‘these constellations are visible at any hour of the night’

> **any** *pronoun*
> 1 [usually with negative or in questions]
> One or some of a thing or number of things, no matter how much or how many.
> ‘someone asked him for a match, but Joe didn't have any’

---

If the *determiner entry 2* sense is used, then being "ineligible for any exemption" carries the sense of requiring ineligibility for every exemption - there is a "lack of restriction" in selecting the exemptions that are ineligible. Here's an example that brings out this sense:

- If you don't pick any of the menu items, you will go hungry.

Defeating the condition requires defeating just one of the possible cases (picking one of the menu items means you don't go hungry; you don't have to pick all of them). This has a similar structure to your first party's assertion, except that if there is eligibility for one exemption, the result *doesn't* apply.

---

If the *pronoun entry 1* sense is used, then being "ineligible for any exemption" refers to being ineligible for any specific exemption. It doesn't matter that there are other exemptions for which ineligibility doesn't apply. Here are a couple of examples that bring out this sense:

- If you like any of these items, you may select it.
- If you can't fit into any of these dresses, please don't try it on. (This doesn't prohibit trying on the ones that do fit.)

Defeating the condition here requires defeating every case. Here, your second party's assertion would hold - the result applies in the event of ineligibility for at least one exemption.

---

The usual way to resolve this ambiguity is to look to the context or determine intent via some other mechanism. For legal disputes, though, you'll need to seek professional advice as there may be provisions in place for handling ambiguity, or for favouring one interpretation over another in law.

Comment: The pronoun usage is not relevant here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, why not?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm trying to bring out the 'any = every' vs 'any = one or more' senses. If you think a different definition fits better, please feel free to edit.

Comment: @Ken N 'If the debtor is ineligible for any exemption, the [result occurs]' clearly uses 'any' as a determiner. But this doesn't guarantee that there is a unique interpretation. // Using 'somehow related' definitions of intercategorial polysemes is inadmissible.

Comment: https://casetext.com/case/ulrich-v-kauer